# Admob banner not showing but with test id it shows

Tags: java, android, admob

Hey guys I am pretty new in android studio but I have code an app which I have uploaded in google play store. My Problem is that I implemented a google admob banner and if I use a test id it show but when I put my real id in the code it not show. I also have wait 7 days and I tested it on 4 devices.

Here is how I implemented the banner and the output of the logcat.
onCreate method

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-2068566232482245~4672139653");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

xml layout code

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="648dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2068566232482245/9043517552"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

build file

```
  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

logcat

```
 2019-04-19 22:13:38.962 12794-12887/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
2019-04-19 22:13:39.165 12794-12875/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Unsupported class loader
2019-04-19 22:13:39.284 12794-12875/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2019-04-19 22:13:39.289 12794-12875/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11210
2019-04-19 22:13:39.289 12794-12875/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11210
2019-04-19 22:13:39.365 12794-12875/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Unsupported class loader
2019-04-19 22:13:39.379 12794-12875/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2019-04-19 22:13:39.444 12794-12910/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Unsupported class loader
2019-04-19 22:13:39.452 12794-12910/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2019-04-19 22:13:39.717 12794-12943/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/Ads: App measurement is starting up, version: 14711
2019-04-19 22:13:39.717 12794-12943/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/Ads: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2019-04-19 22:13:41.348 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c6fa434
2019-04-19 22:13:41.374 12794-12910/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/Ads: Got on activity created
2019-04-19 22:13:41.459 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/allgemeinwisse: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-04-19 22:13:41.468 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/allgemeinwisse: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-04-19 22:13:41.531 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11210
2019-04-19 22:13:41.532 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11210
2019-04-19 22:13:41.536 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
2019-04-19 22:13:41.570 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
2019-04-19 22:13:41.594 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 73.0.3683.90 (code 368309052)
2019-04-19 22:13:41.694 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 4 ms (timestamps 6897-6901)
2019-04-19 22:13:41.725 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(50)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2019-04-19 22:13:41.726 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "73.0.3683.90", actual native library version number "73.0.3683.90"
2019-04-19 22:13:42.025 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
2019-04-19 22:13:42.044 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3D3E1F542ADD0C690202584E49A7D658") to get test ads on this device.
2019-04-19 22:13:42.097 12794-13205/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
2019-04-19 22:13:42.097 12794-13205/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
2019-04-19 22:13:42.105 12794-13151/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/allgemeinwisse: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-04-19 22:13:42.112 12794-13206/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11210
2019-04-19 22:13:42.112 12794-13206/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11210
2019-04-19 22:13:42.254 12794-13153/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/allgemeinwisse: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-19 22:13:42.273 12794-13151/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
2019-04-19 22:13:42.360 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-04-19 22:13:42.434 12794-13152/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
2019-04-19 22:13:42.884 12794-12794/de.androidnewcomer.quizallgemeinwissen D/ViewRootImpl@582a837[MainActivity]: Surface release. an
```

Comment: It takes time to load real ads on the device and the alternate way to test it to install it on other devices.

Comment: `AdRequest` also provide a listener . Set a listener and Check Error Code .

Comment: logcat: I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3D3E1F542ADD0C690202584E49A7D658") to get test ads on this device.

Comment: You need to setup payment method for real Ads

Comment: Thank you all so much for help I find out the error and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

please try to add testDevice in adRequest, this works for me.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
```

you can also create adlistener to track your ads.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    Log.e("onAdLoaded","AdLoaded");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                    Log.e("onAdFailedToLoad",""+errorCode);

                }
            });
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: now it shows me that in the logcat  E/onAdFailedToLoad: 0

Comment: @julianpjp - now try to remove addTestDevice and you will get the error code or You just need to wait a little. Your ad id is newly created so it will take some time to fetch ads from google servers. So give it some time and it will work soon. At least for me, it happens all the time. Can't surely say for you but why not give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the meta-data inside the tag application

`<!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
<application>....
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>`